# ¿Porque marca error al agregar aplicación en IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server

El detalle es que estoy haciendo un tipo intranet, tengo otras aplicaciones que deseo ir adjuntado en un solo puerto, el detalle viene que publico mi aplicación así:

1. Aplicación que funcionara como intranet va así, Pulse en sitios, de ahí puse agregar sitios web y busque la ruta de mi proyecto quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. para agregar la siguiente aplicación pulse sobre App-IIS, y pulse agregar aplicación, igual busque su ruta, quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al examinar la aplicación adjunta que llamen app-facturas: me tira los siguientes errores:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) runtime-es2015.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
styles.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
polyfills-es2015.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
vendor-es2015.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
main-es2015.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
scripts.js:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
favicon.ico:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
styles.css:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Y si accedo a mi aplicación principal se ve sin ningún problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se si falte alguna configuración o algo parecido, todo esta desarrollado con angular 8 y .net core 3.1, todo creado en visual studio 2019.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

La manera en que la publique fue primero hacer esto desde visual studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de ahí se generaron los archivos en mi disco local, después copie al servidor en estas carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé así dejándolas por separado y hacer referencia y la otra fue introducir la carpeta App-Facturas dentro de Apps-IIS

Pero siguen marcando error, la estructura de cada carpeta es esta :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Cree una carpeta y pegue el contenido de la aplicación de la app secundaria
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de ahí accedí hasta la aplicación donde se ubica y ejecute el archivo .exe y dio este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si accedo a la dirección de manera local accede así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al inspeccionar la aplicación desde IIS marca estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al tratar de acceder desde una pc distinta da el error este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A pesar de que en el firewall puse el puerto, y su accedo  a la aplicación principal marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes un error 500 cuando intenta traer los recursos que aparecen en la salida de la consola (style.css..etc), los estas referenciando bien ?

Comment: Si, porque si la publico por separado si funcionan

Comment: Faltan datos. ¿Cómo realizas la publicación de tu proyecto? ¿Cúales son las rutas a las que llama desde el frontend? ¿Cuáles son las rutas habilitadas en el backend?

Comment: Tienes 2 aplicaciones separadas (angular + API) y quieres publicarlas en el mismo sitio? Suponiendo que es eso, y que las carpetas wwwroot y ClientApp se refiere a ambas aplicaciones. En el menú izquierdo selecciona esas capertas, haz click derecho y pones "convertir en aplicación"

Comment: intente convertirlas en aplicación pero no funciono, solamente funciona si las dejo por separado

Comment: A ver si ahora entendí: Tienes 2 aplicaciones una principal (Apps-IIS) y la otra es una subaplicación (app-facturas) que quieres poner dentro de la primera ??? Y ambas aplicaciones son .net + angular???

Comment: Si eso es lo que deseo realizar

Comment: Primero debes publicar el sitio (Apps-IIS), tal como lo tienes en las 2 primeras imágenes. Luego crea una carpeta dentro que se llame App-facturas y pegas el contenido de esa APP. Es decir en Apps-IIS tendrás 3 carpetas (ClientApp, wwwroot y App-facturas). Luego en el IIS conviertes a aplicación a App-facturas

Comment: Suponiendo que lo dicho anteriormente ya lo has hecho, entra en modo consola hasta la carpeta App-facturas y ejecuta Factura.exe para verificar si arroja algún error

Comment: Probare eso, ya que si marca errores y espero con eso solucionarlo

Comment: Actualice la pregunta

Comment: El último error, creo que se refiere a que debes tener diferente pool de aplicación para Apps-IIS. Por ejemplo, en tu segunda imagen, en la ventana emergente hay un campo que dice "Grupo de Aplicaciones", Ahí debes seleccionar (y crear si es necesario) un única para esta app

Comment: Pensé en lo mismo, pero no funciona sobre el puerto 81 y si intento abrir el 5001 desde otra pc no funciona

Comment: Utilize un pool diferente para cada una de las aplicaciones , además intente cambiando la configuración del pool por ejemplo habilitandole 32 bits o bien que si es una aplicación de net core el pool no sea de net framework dependiente , adicional revise que las carpetas tengan full permisos en el wwroot. Normalmente el pool de netcore debe ser el que dice "No manage code" o algo así

Comment: Intentare lo del pool, porque si tiene acceso de compartir todo para poder ver la aplicación